# How to use Multiple prompts using langchain

Tags: chatbot, prompt, openai-api, agent, langchain

I want to use multiple prompts to do my tasks. I have written a prompt for document question answering that utilizes chat history and context to answer question. Now I want to my model to generate invoice based on the chat history. I have written another prompt for this. Is there any method for using multiple prompts in such a way that my model uses his intelligence to determine which prompt to run? First I have tried using prompt pipelining form langchain but didn't get exceptional results because the input variable are creating an issue.

For Document question prompt my model have 4 input variables

````
DEFAULT_TEMPLATE = """
### Instruction: Your name is 'Jarvis' and the name of the customer is {username}. Please introduce yourself as 'Jarvis, Information Assistant'. Use the user's name occasionally in your responses, but ensure to introduce yourself only in the first response.
Utilize the chat history and available information in "{context}" to answer the question.
Remember, the user is looking for assistance, so keep your responses natural, concise, accurate, and informative. If you are uncertain about a query or if the user asked something which is unidentified by you, prompt the user to rephrase it. 
When greeted, respond briefly and amiably.
{chat_history}
### Input: {question}
### Response:
"""

prompt = PromptTemplate (
        input_variables = ["context", "question", "chat_history", "username"],
        template = DEFAULT_TEMPLATE,```
````

For Invoice generation I'm passing chat history to another prompt and telling my model to format this in json format and create a table.

Is there any way that my model will determine by user's question that which prompt to run?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way that my model will determine by user's question that which prompt to run?

You can look into [OpenAI function calling](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/function-calling), but I'm afraid you'll have to define the functions and schemas (pydantic might help?) yourself. Also, there's no guarantee it will call the function/correct function/any function at all.

I see you're using langchain but I find its documentation written poorly so cannot find the exact thing. Probably [this](https://python.langchain.com/docs/expression_language/how_to/functions). You might also have to look at chains.